# How to match two text files, find matches and replace with original content?

Tags: python, regex

Basically I have 2 text files.

**Text file A:(repeated strings)**

```
hg17_chr2_74388709_74389
hg17_chr5_137023651_1370
hg17_chr7_137880501_1378
hg17_chr5_137023651_1370
```

**Text file B:**

```
hg17_chrX_52804801_52805856
hg17_chr15_79056833_79057564
hg17_chr2_74388709_74389559
hg17_chr1_120098891_120099441
hg17_chr5_137023651_137024301
hg17_chr11_85997073_85997627
hg17_chr7_137880501_137881251
```

File A was trimmed by a tool therefore the match can be found to be exact the same for the first 24 characters of each string for both file.  How to match both files and output the result in a new file with desired content:

```
hg17_chr2_74388709_74389559
hg17_chr5_137023651_137024301
hg17_chr7_137880501_137881251
hg17_chr5_137023651_137024301
```

Comment: What did you tried? Perhaps you find useful packages [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and function write

Comment: Is there any need for regex here at all? If one of the files have the very same strings that have been cut from the right side you can just have two sorted lists to compare each element of one of them with `startswith()` of the other one. And replace the shorter one with the longer one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution with only opening the files once:

```
with open('file_a','r') as fa:  # open file a --> read the files into lists
    list_a = fa.read().splitlines()
with open('file_b','r') as fb:  # open file b --> read the files into lists
    list_b = fb.read().splitlines()

# get element in list_b if list_a contain the element(only first 24 characters)
match_list = [n for n in list_b if n[:24] in list_a]

with open('file_c','w+') as fc:  # write the matching list to the new file
    fc.write('\n'.join(match_list))
```

Comment: Only return me the last string output.

Comment: @Allyson i updated my code. works for me in python2&3

Comment: if I have repeated string in file A, the output will only return one type of string. How to remain the output string?

Answer (score 1):

This could be an option to consider

```
 with open("file_C.txt", "w") as f_3:  # Open file C
    with open("file_A.txt") as f_1:  # Open file A
        for line_a in f_1:  # Iterates over each line in file A
            with open("file_B.txt") as f_2 : # Open file B
                for line_b in f_2:  # Iterates over each line in file B
                    # If line in file B starts as line in file A
                    if line_b.startswith(line_a.rstrip()): 
                        f_3.write(line_b)  # Write line of file B
                        # breaks the loop of file_b 
                        # to continue with the next line in file_a
                        break
```

Comment: You'd better sort them before iteration. Will save you a lot of time.

Comment: To sort them I should load all the lines, and depending on the files length I wouldn't try. But if the files are short then of course, but being this chromosomes positions of something the list can be quite large

Comment: Well, that depends on the memory available and the ammount of data, obviously.

Comment: @Llopis Hi I just tried your code. It only return the last item instead of three items. Thanks

Comment: Now would work, but you could have read it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)...

Comment: read function is nt defined so I changed it to open function. Your third line of code produce error is there missing colon? The output is not correct.

Comment: Totally true I  hope now the issues are solved. But you can also create the file_C before iterating over the other files

Comment: Yes I changed it to saving my output by creating a new file. Still it give me only one string instead of three strings.

Comment: Then if you create the file at the beginning as I told you it should work

Comment: Yes I did create at the beginning. But it doesn't return 3 strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78777/discussion-between-llopis-and-allyson).